# onPropertyChanged - How to switch propertyId from external class

Tags: android-databinding

I have a model that extends BaseObservable.  I have a view model that contains a reference to the model and subscribes to property changes within the model.  How do I switch on the Model.propertyId from within the callback in the view model?  In the sample below BR.assignedId is the property in the model.  For example:

**View Model**

```
public void onPropertyChanged(Observable sender, int propertyId)
{

    switch (propertyId)
    {
        case MyModel.BR.assignedId://compile error
            notifyPropertyChanged(BR.assignedImage);
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to read Observer pattern. The code above has Entities : Observer and Observable. Observer has an Observing method.  Any class which wants to observe the 'Observable' needs to register itself as 'Observer'. Observable calls the observing method on the Observer and this is how the usual call back works. (names of classes and methods may be differnt , I used as per the intent and context)

Check  'ViewModel.java' class would be implementing some 'observer' interface which would be having the method  'onPropertyChanged ()'. you will have to set the object of ViewModel.java in Model.java. (check you should be having a method with a name like addPropertyChangeObserver (), though it may be differnt but similar method. Use this method to set the object of ViewModel.java in Model.java. Now Model.java would call the method 'onPropertyChanged' on ViewModel.java.

if you wish to modify something on the Model then check the sender parameter. You can add another method in the interface implemented by Model and can do modifications on Model using it or can simply typecast the sender after checking its type with instanceof and can perform the process on Model.java from the callback method.

Comment: Yes the code currently does everything you describe above.  My model calls my view just fine.  The problem is I don't know how to handle the propertyID.  I want to run different code based which model property changed.  Does that make sense?

Comment: I don't want to modify anything in the model.  Basically, an ID in the model changes and I need to update an image contained in the view model which is displayed in the view.  I accomplish this by notifying the view my image has changed. I can only do that after my model changes the id.  I also have other properties which require similar reactions to model changes.